# Apache2 cannot load mod_tile

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I had installed mod_tile and apache2 and tile server worked without problem. after that i installed php5.5.3. it changed all file structures of apache2 conf. i think something has changed. "LoadModule tile_module"had been removed from the config file. I added it in new apache2.conf file. but now when i restart apache it shows this message:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_tile.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so: undefined symbol: unixd_set_global_mutex_perms
>   Action 'configtest' failed.

and this is /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod_tile.conf

```
LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so
```

Comment: That [mod_tile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile) doesn't seem to have any relation with PHP. Have you also upgraded Apache itself?

Comment: Yes it has not any relation with php. I think it was dependecy for php5.5.3 to upgrade apache

Comment: Apache modules need to be recompiled for each Apache version. If you've upgraded Apache you'll need to get or make a new `mod_tile` binary.